# Why does tmux not insert newlines when pasting a multi-line command?

Tags: bash, shell, paste, tmux

I often use a REPL-style coding method when writing shell scripts (or other relevant languages), and recently noticed the following issue. I run tmux so I can have my script open in vim in a pane side-by-side with a terminal prompt.

### Tmux

If I try to paste multiple lines of commands at once using CMD-v on a Mac, i.e.

```
a=hello
b=World
echo $a $b
```

tmux does not process the newlines properly, but instead gives the following output:

```
[user@host: ~]$ a=hello
b='World'
echo $a $b
[user@host: ~]$ b='World'echo $a $b
```

If I clear the prompt, and run `echo $a`, I get `hello` echo'ed to the screen, but `echo $b` produces an empty line, and obviously the `echo $a $b` line does not get run.

I get the same output using a REPL like `gnuplot`, or when using `rlwrap`.

#### Alternate tmux attempt

The same issue occurs when using [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime/blob/master/plugin/slime.vim), or using the relevant vim-slime system calls manually:

```
[user@host: ~]$ tmux set-buffer 'a=hello
> b=World
> echo $a $b
> '
[user@host: ~]$ tmux paste-buffer -p
a=hello
b=World
echo $a $b
[user@host: ~]$ a=hellob=Worldecho $a $b
```

I have tried `tmux paste-buffer` with, and without the `-p` flag for [bracketed paste mode](http://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste).

### Plain bash shell, or GNU screen

If I perform the same CMD-v paste action in a normal bash shell (not in tmux), I get:

```
[user@host: ~]$ a=hello
[user@host: ~]$ b=World
[user@host: ~]$ echo $a $b
hello World
[user@host: ~]$
```

as expected. I get the same output when pasting in GNU screen (v4.04.00).

## Question

Why does tmux not process the pasted commands line-by-line, as bash/gnu screen do? How do we fix this problem?

#### Already asked?

The same issue appears to have been asked at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455383/pasting-a-large-chunk-of-code-to-tmux-on-mac-osx), and [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825563/pasting-a-large-amount-of-text-into-the-clojure-repl-running-in-tmux-results-in), but not yet answered satisfactorily.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810733/print-bash-script-result-behind-prompt-in-the-next-line) offers a solution of a `sleep` line between each command, which does the trick, but it's a bit of a hack to assume how long each command will take to process before sending the next line of text. There must be a better way.

### Versions

I am running Mac OS X El Capitan (v10.11.6), iTerm2 (v3.0.10), tmux (v2.2), GNU bash (v4.4.0).

The same results can be reproduced using Terminal.app (v2.6).

Comment: Can you reproduce this with completely empty .tmux.conf and .bashrc files? Are you using some sort of clipboard manager that could be coming into play?

This is curious, as I'm not having this issue, and I'm running the same versions of OSX, iTerm2, and tmux.

Comment: Ah, I am using `reattach-to-user-namespace` as a wrapper to get access to the mac os clipboard ([this github repo](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/blob/master/README.md)), which seems to be causing the problem. Copy/paste seems to be a constant headache with vim/tmux/mac os so I'd appreciate any suggestions for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had been using `reattach-to-user-namespace` to interact with the OS X clipboard; however, according to the `reattach-to-user-namespace` [github page](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard):

> Note: Under Yosemite (and later) pasteboard access seems to work fine
>   without the program from this repository.

I removed the `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"` line from my `.tmux.conf` file. I also changed my tmux mapping to

```
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```

and it copies text to the OS X clipboard from vi-copy mode as expected. Pasting text using the OS X default Cmd-v produces the expected behavior (like in screen or plain bash shell as described in the question). Thanks to @Alex Torok for prompting my config file debugging.

Comment: I don't have the `reattach-to-user-namespace` in my `tmux.conf` and adding the `bind` command above did not solve my problem. So pasting still doesn't work with tmux (3.2 or 3.3).